# ListBoxEdit: How can i make the image and the textbox selectable?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

The listBoxItem is defined like this:

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit
                    MouseDoubleClick="OnListViewMouseDoubleClick"
                    DisplayMember="Name"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleDataTemplate}"
                    Name="listOfPeople"
                    ValueMember="ID">
            </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

The Person class contains two properties:

```
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
```

In code behind i try to get the details of the person with the next sentence but is always null. The details I want to be shown in a second windows xaml view.

```
PersonDetails secondView = new PersonDetails();
secondView.PersonItems = listOfPeople.SelectedItems.Cast<Person>();
editWindow.Show();
```

PersonItems is defined as:

```
 public List<Person> PersonItems { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="PeopleDataTemplate">
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem MouseDoubleClick="OnListViewMouseDoubleClick">
                <StackPanel Width="100" Margin="5">
                    <Image
                        Width="75"
                        Height="75"
                        Source="{Binding Picture}">
                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Image.ToolTip>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}  {1}">
                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </dxe:ListBoxEditItem>
        </DataTemplate>
 </UserControl.Resources>

<dxe:ListBoxEdit
                    MouseDoubleClick="OnListViewMouseDoubleClick"
                    DisplayMember="Name"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleDataTemplate}"
                    Name="listOfPeople"
                    ValueMember="ID">
            </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

If I push after the textbox ends, then the item is selected, but if i press on the picture or into the name textbox, the selection is not happening. Why?

Comment: You bind your ListBoxEdit to the Name property of menbers of the Persons collection. Where are those defined?

Comment: @mami Is defined in the view model class. I obtain a list like:
<Picture><LastName + FirstName><<empty>>
<Picture><LastName + FirstName><<empty>>
.
.
.
If i press the <picture> or <Name + firstName> field -> item is not selected
If i press after <Name + firstName> -> item is selected
Why this happen?